# Sagemaker - XGBOOST rank:ndcg

Tags: xgboost, aws, sagemaker

Does anyone know if the rank:ndcg is available on AWS Sagemaker? I am currently trying to run a model, but it seems like it's not implemented. Am I using an older xgboost version? Kinda new to AWS Sagemaker, so if you have any tutorials/docs, shoot them over.